# What are the units (meters/kilometers/feet etc.) for cylinder radius while creating cylinder using Cesium API

Tags: cesiumjs

What are the units (meters/kilometers/feet etc.) for cylinder **radius** while creating cylinder using **Cesium API**.

Refer code below:

What are the units of `cylinderRadius` and `cylinderUpperHeight`?

```
viewer.entities.add({
  name : "",
  position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(longitude, latitude, altitude),
  cylinder : {
     length : cylinderUpperHeight,
     topRadius : cylinderRadius,
     bottomRadius : cylinderRadius,
     material : Cesium.Color.GREEN.withAlpha(0.2),
     outline : true,
     outlineColor : Cesium.Color.GREEN.withAlpha(0.2)
 },
 description: description
});
```

I have the input for them in **nautical miles** so I have to convert them to required units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cesium uses **SI units**:

- meters for distances,
- radians for angles,
- seconds for time
  durations.

**Converstion from Nautical Miles to meter**

1 Nautical Mile = 1852 Meters